# R match two character columns in one tibble with two other character columns in another tibble

Tags: r

Say I have two objects,

```
mixed
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  genus        epithet   
  <chr>        <chr>     
1 Vincetoxicum nigrum    
2 Rosa         multiflora
3 Quercus      rubra     
4 Acer         saccharum 
5 Rosa         pendula   
6 Vincetoxicum nigrum    
7 Vincetoxicum nigrum
```

and

```
invasives
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  genus        epithet   
  <chr>        <chr>     
1 Larix        pendula   
2 Picea        abies     
3 Rosa         multiflora
4 Vincetoxicum nigrum
```

I want to check whether both columns of "mixed" match with both the columns of "invasives", and get an index that would allow me to pull those matching from "mixed". Note that "pendula" is in "epithet" in both "mixed" and "invasives", but its corresponding row in the first column has "Larix" in "invasives" and "Rosa" in "mixed", so it is not included in the final product.

So once that index was created, I'm thinking I'd want to run:

```
columns_matched <- mixed[index,]
```

yielding:

```
columns_matched
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  genus        epithet   
  <chr>        <chr>     
1 Vincetoxicum nigrum    
2 Rosa         multiflora 
3 Vincetoxicum nigrum    
4 Vincetoxicum nigrum
```

csv versions of the tables:

```
genus,epithet
Vincetoxicum,nigrum
Rosa,multiflora
Quercus,rubra
Acer,saccharum
Rosa,pendula
Vincetoxicum,nigrum
Vincetoxicum,nigrum

genus,epithet
Larix,pendula
Picea,abies
Rosa,multiflora
Vincetoxicum,nigrum
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest answer that comes to mind is to just `inner_join` your data-sets.
This way, only identical rows are left over:

```r
library(tidyverse)
mixed <- read_csv('genus,epithet
Vincetoxicum,nigrum
Rosa,multiflora
Quercus,rubra
Acer,saccharum
Rosa,pendula
Vincetoxicum,nigrum
Vincetoxicum,nigrum')
#> Rows: 7 Columns: 2
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: ","
#> chr (2): genus, epithet
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.

invasives <- read_csv('genus,epithet
Larix,pendula
Picea,abies
Rosa,multiflora
Vincetoxicum,nigrum')
#> Rows: 4 Columns: 2
#> ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#> Delimiter: ","
#> chr (2): genus, epithet
#> 
#> ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
#> ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.


mixed %>% 
  inner_join(invasives)
#> Joining, by = c("genus", "epithet")
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   genus        epithet   
#>   <chr>        <chr>     
#> 1 Vincetoxicum nigrum    
#> 2 Rosa         multiflora
#> 3 Vincetoxicum nigrum    
#> 4 Vincetoxicum nigrum
```

If you really wanted to have that index, you could just add a dummy-column to your mixed-tibble:

```r
index <- mixed %>% 
  mutate(index = seq_along(genus)) %>% 
  inner_join(invasives) %>% 
  pull(index)
#> Joining, by = c("genus", "epithet")

mixed[index,]
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   genus        epithet   
#>   <chr>        <chr>     
#> 1 Vincetoxicum nigrum    
#> 2 Rosa         multiflora
#> 3 Vincetoxicum nigrum    
#> 4 Vincetoxicum nigrum
```

Comment: Thank you! I would upvote but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: I guess a follow up question would be: what if there were also more than two columns? In the sense that, say we had another column in each table called, TaxonRank, or something, just some other column of any kind, where we couldn't do (at least from what I can tell) a simple inner_join. This still works for me, but anyway, that's the other thing I'd wonder.

Comment: using the `by`-argument of the join functions you can define the columns you want to join on. If you add `by = c('genus','epithet')` to the join-call, your other columns should not matter.

Comment: Ok great thank you!